# Clearing Hibernate Second-Level Caches

Tags: java, hibernate

Recently uses the secondary level cache  in my project there
   is some issue with it , i  wanted to know how can i clear it  secondary cache

Comment: do you want to disable cache/ clear the cache at some point of time ?

Comment: Your problem is very similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461063/springhibernateehcache-how-to-clear-all-cache)

Comment: sessionFactory.getCache().evictEntityRegions(); try this

Answer (score 8):

If you want to clear cache in code you can use:

```
sf.getCache().evictEntityRegions()
sf.getCache().evictCollectionRegions()
sf.getCache().evictDefaultQueryRegion()
sf.getCache().evictQueryRegions()
```

where `sf` means session factory