# How to clear the second level cache in hibernate5.0

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to using using Hibernate 2nd level cache in my spring boot application which will run in pcf. can any one help me in clearing the cache and also post some sample code snippet please.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461063/how-to-clear-all-hibernate-cache-ehcache-using-spring).

Comment: and [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching-management-evict).